# Calculating the mean vectors for a two-factorial table

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I am trying to calculate the mean reagent vectors across the variables `RBC`, `WBC`, and `hemoglobin`. I am fairly new to R so my question is: Can you show me an easier way to do the following calculations in R? The data is from Table 6.19 of [Rencher](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470178965). I am trying to practice doing the computations in R as I follow the examples in Rencher.

```
reagent.dat <- read.table("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28713619/reagent.dat")
colnames(reagent.dat) <- c("reagent", "subject", "RBC", "WBC", "hemoglobin")
reagent.dat$reagent <- factor(reagent.dat$reagent)
reagent.dat$subject <- factor(reagent.dat$subject)
library(plyr) 
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
# Calculate the means per variable, across reagents
reagent.datm <- melt(reagent.dat)
group.means <- ddply(reagent.datm, c("variable","reagent"), summarise,mean=mean(value))
group.means <- tbl_df(group.means)
newdata <- group.means %>% select(reagent, mean)
# Store the group means into a matrix
y_bar <- matrix(c(rep(NA, times=12)), ncol=4)
for (i in 1:4)
  y_bar[,i] <- as.matrix(filter(newdata, reagent == i)$mean, ncol=1)
y_bar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dplyr` package can actually simplify your code quite easily and is definitely worth learning because of how powerful it can be. As an example:

```
reagent.dat <- read.table("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28713619/reagent.dat")
colnames(reagent.dat) <- c("reagent", "subject", "RBC", "WBC", "hemoglobin")

#Using dplyr
library(dplyr)
reagentmeans <- reagent.dat  %>% select(reagent, RBC, WBC, hemoglobin)  %>% 
group_by(reagent)  %>% 
summarize(mean_RBC = mean(RBC), mean_WBC = mean(WBC),
 mean_hemoglobin = mean(hemoglobin))

> reagentmeans
Source: local data frame [4 x 4]

  reagent mean_RBC mean_WBC mean_hemoglobin
   (fctr)    (dbl)    (dbl)           (dbl)
1       1    7.290   4.9535          15.310
2       2    7.210   4.8985          15.725
3       3    7.055   4.8810          15.595
4       4    7.025   4.8915          15.765
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out about the `summarize` and `group_by`. I'll follow your advice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `data.table`,

```
library(data.table)
setDT(reagent.dat)[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = reagent, .SDcols = c('RBC', 'WBC', 'hemoglobin')]
#   reagent   RBC    WBC hemoglobin
#1:       1 7.290 4.9535     15.310
#2:       2 7.210 4.8985     15.725
#3:       3 7.055 4.8810     15.595
#4:       4 7.025 4.8915     15.765
```

Comment: This is the first time I heard of `data.table`. Thank you.

Comment: Much more efficient than data.frames.